# User credential verification failed when configuring Visual Studio MVC authentication

Tags: authentication, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

When creating a new MVC app and clicking "change authentication".

After choosing "multiple organisations" clicking finish and logging in with my Microsoft account (the one used for Azure) I receive the following error:

> User credential verification failed.
>
> Error: Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: entity

Any ideas?

The error is very generic so has proved tricky to find a hint of what to try next.

### EDIT:

I have remembered that I have Update 2 RC installed, so it's possible it's just a bug in the pre release.

[image]

Comment: Migrated from http://superuser.com/questions/752450/user-credential-verification-failed-when-configuring-visual-studio-mvc-authentic

Comment: Just a note - before Update 2 was released (today, I think) Visual studio was crashing when I clicked OK.. Then I noticed an update notification, at which point I started getting this message. My guess is this is due to an update on their backend as well, but can't find any other details..

Comment: Cool thanks @ArtiomChilaru it's good to know it's been released fully. Perhaps they'll release another patch shortly to fix this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I believe I have the answer to the issue.. Seems like this login dialog lets you log in using the Azure AD accounts, but also using Microsoft's accounts. And if you log in using the Microsoft account, it will give this error (even if this MS account has full access to your Azure account).

The solution is to go to the Active Directory in Azure and create a brand new account, mark it as a Global Administrator, then use that to log in when prompted in Visual Studio.

Microsoft has a write-up on the issue, describing the steps to go around it here: 
http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/12/11/setting-up-an-asp-net-project-with-organizational-authentication-requires-an-organizational-account/

Comment: Thanks, I realised I never had a chance to test this out when you posted it - I'm unsure if this is an issue now as so much has changed in Azure generally and I don't have the same setup anymore. I'll mark this as the answer anyway as it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Restart VS. So that you wont get the same error again and clears the logged in user. You would need a user with Global Admin Rights in your Azure AD to login again.

Comment: Thanks I don't have the setup anymore to test this out, but thanks for the answer.